# Running PCIE card with the on board video card as well in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, pci-express

I have an emachines Windows7 PC. I am trying to run the on board video card along with the dual DVI card I installed in the PCIE slot. In CMOS it shows the on board card as disabled and it will not let me enable it? Its greyed out so I cant even highlight it to change anything.

I have done this before in XP on a few different machines so I know its possible, Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a XP vs. Windows Vista or 7 issue... what you are describing is a motherboard issue.

I would check for an updated BIOS, but in many cases you don't have a choice whether onboard video is disabled or not when installing an add-in graphics card. Sometimes, manufacturers make this decision to reduce confusion (there are many people who install a graphics card and then plug their monitor into the onboard VGA/DVI socket). Or the motherboard design will turnoff the internal graphics and re-route the PCI-E lanes from the onboard chip to the graphics card you installed.

Comment: Dustin is correct. This is a function of the mainboard (and not an advertised one, either), not the OS. Some chipsets support this ability, most do not. And BIOS updates do not usually change this support.

Answer (score 0):

Vista and W7 are not as friendly towards multiple video cards as XP was

http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2006/12/vista-limitation-multi-monitor-displays/

> If you have two different video cards that have different WDDM Drivers – one will be disabled

No work around that I know of.